# Kubernetes run mariadb pod use pv hostpath. Occur File system loop detected in '/var/lib/mysql'

Tags: kubernetes, mariadb, kubernetes-pvc

I have used minikube tunnel connect local folder to mount /mnt/data/mysql .

I used yaml below...

mariadb-data-pv.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mariadb-data-pv-volume
spec:
  storageClassName: stardard
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce # 單一Pod 讀/寫
  hostPath:
    path: /var/lib/mysql
    type: "DirectoryOrCreate"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mariadb-data-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: stardard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

kubernetes-mariadb-deployment.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mariadb-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dev
  replicas: 1
  minReadySeconds: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dev
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mariadb
        image: mariadb:10.4.31
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "512Mi"
            cpu: "1500m"
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: "myP@ssword"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mariadb-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /mnt/data/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mariadb-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mariadb-data-pv-claim
```

then execute command

```
kubectl apply -f .\persistents\mariadb-data-pv.yaml
kubectl apply -f .\deployments\kubernetes-mariadb-deployment.yaml
```

Question:
First time init the pod is work. And create a database named "sampledb". I can see the container /var/lib/mysql data has transfer to my local computer /mnt/data/mysql directory.

But When I used `kubectl delete -f .`. try to run pod again. It has error below:

```
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.4.31+maria~ubu2004 started.
find: File system loop detected; ‘/var/lib/mysql/hwuc’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/var/lib/mysql/’.
```

Has anyone experienced this problem or has any advice on it?

I have try update mariadb version to 10.5.22 and 10.3.38 still get same error.

-------- Update 2023.11.3 --------

Solve this problem.

found when used `minikube mount /mnt/data:/mnt/data` cause this error.

Comment: `mountPath: /mnt/data/mysql` looks odd. MariaDB expects its data in `/var/lib/mysql` as the `mountPath` inside the its container. If it wasn't there a `--datadir` would be needed as the `command` to move it.

Comment: Sorry, I saw it. It should be my input error. The `mountPath` of mariadb-persistent-storage should be '/var/lib/mysql'
But the problem cannot be solved. This loop detect error still exists.

Comment: fyi question edits are encouraged. `find` is just the gnu prog executed in the entrypoint, so same problem as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153761/find-file-system-loop-detected), a binded path down a hierarchy. Volumes are created will bind mounts and filesystem namespaces (similar to chroots).

Comment: @Felix How did you solve the problem then? If you did not use "minikube mount", how could you mount the data in your local directory to the database? I faced a similar problem, only I was using MongoDB.

Comment: @GreenPenguin After trying various methods, I have decided to give up on directly mounting to a local folder and instead, I'll let the data remain within the container of Minikube. Anyway, as long as I don't execute minikube delete, the data will be preserved inside the container upon the next startup.